# How to get hostname using UDP c#

Tags: c#, udp

I got ip address and port number. Now I need to get hostname any advice?
I got following code to get ip and port number.
 static void Main(string[] args)
            {

```
            System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient server = new System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient(15000);
            IPEndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        data = server.Receive(ref sender);
        server.Close();
        string stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, data.Length);


        Console.WriteLine("Response from " + sender.Address + Environment.NewLine + "Port number is " + sender.Port.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + "Message: " + stringData);


        Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to use `DNS.GetHostEntry()`

Some sample code:

```
using System;  
using System.Net;  

class DNSTest  
{  
    static void Main()  
    {  
        // Do a few lookups by host name and address  
        DNSLookup("msdn.microsoft.com");  
        DNSLookup("207.46.16.248");  

        // Keep the console window open in debug mode  
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");  
        Console.ReadKey();  
    }  

    protected static void DNSLookup(string hostNameOrAddress)  
    {  
        Console.WriteLine("Lookup: {0}\n", hostNameOrAddress);  

        IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostNameOrAddress);  
        Console.WriteLine("  Host Name: {0}", hostEntry.HostName);  

        IPAddress[] ips = hostEntry.AddressList;  
        foreach (IPAddress ip in ips)  
        {  
            Console.WriteLine("  Address: {0}", ip);  
        }  

        Console.WriteLine();  
    }  
}
```

This code example comes from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/518e1bcb-6df6-4d42-8491-07af6ee4319f/c-systemsystemdiagnosticsprocess-nslookup?forum=netfxbcl)

Comment: I just got hostname using this code 
Console.WriteLine(Dns.GetHostName()); Anyway thanks avitus